# Currency Conversion calculation

Tags: foreign-exchange

Currently the conversion rate from US to Canada is 1.32 and going from Canada to US is 0.76. If one only knew the currency rate of US to Canada (1.32) is there a way to calculate (Canada to US)0.76 instead of looking it up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 / 1.32 = 0.76.

1 Canadian Dollar = 0.76 USD.

1 USD = 1.32 CAD.